# Get Item version history in a dialog box on a webpart

Tags: 2013, version-history

I created a web part with all items of different lists, I also added a image button in front of each item, now on click I want to see a dialog box opening with version history of that item.

I think it must be possible, don't want to re-invent the wheel and start doing it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Out the Box Version History Page for displaying this information.

The URL to this page is

```
http://siteurl/_layouts/15/Versions.aspx?list={LISTID}&ID=ITEMID&IsDlg=1
```

You need to replace `LISTID` with your list guid. It will be of form `E3B0E0D6-7053-4CA0-9F24-CC99DE0C0AB1`

Also you need to pass the Id of the item - Replace `ITEMID` with list item id.

For displaying version history as a dialog you can use below JavaScript

```
var options =
{
    title: 'Version History',
    url: 'URL'
}

SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Comment: thank you, is there any work around for not using list id, off course i can get it using code but just wondering, i am going to test your code soon

Comment: `Versions.aspx` is a generic page. So that page needs to know which List the item belongs to. List ID will be Unique across site, while item Id is not unique across site.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a link to your button which takes the user to the Display Form (DispForm.aspx) for the Item?  From the Display Form, they're then able to click on the version history button in the ribbon.

All you need to know is where the item is located, then you can find the relevant Display Form and pass it the ID of the Item.

A typical Display Form may be located at an address like `http://siteCollection/subSite/library/Forms/DispForm.aspx`

If you know the Item ID, you can add it on like so `http://siteCollection/subSite/library/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=1234` then your link takes you to the Display Form showing the particular Item with version history available.

See [SP.List.defaultDisplayFormUrl Property.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee551382(v=office.14).aspx)