# Get last major version of page with all custom field values using JSOM/REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api, publishing-page

We want to access last major version of page **with all its OOTB & custom fields** using JSOM/REST. I can able to get only version number & url only but we need all fields.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, we can use [Lists.GetVersionCollection method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/ms774544(v=office.12)) to return version information for an item in a SharePoint list/library. But it only returns version information for the specified field in a SharePoint list/library. What’s more, there is no such function in the Lists.asmx can help us to get all the versions of all fields in a batch, so we might need to iterate through all the wanted fields one by one.

Refer to my answer in this thread:
[Add Version History details in dispform or editform.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245509/add-version-history-details-in-dispform-or-editform-aspx)

To get the latest major version, you can check the Version values from version collection of Version column. If it is integer, it means it is a major version.

Here is a demo about how to get the last major version for an item in a list/library. For all items, you can retrieve all item ids and execute the commands for each item id.

```
<div id="displayDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/0.7.1a/jquery.SPServices-0.7.1a.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentItemId = "<item ID>"; //you can also loop all item ids from the list/library
var table="<table><tr><th>Version</th><th>Title</th><th>Editor</th><th>Modified</th></tr>";
var html ="";
var fieldname ="";
$(function(){
                var oTitle = getFieldVersion("Title");
                var oVersion = getFieldVersion("Version");
                var oModified = getFieldVersion("Modified");
                var oEditor = getFieldVersion("Editor");
                for (var i = 0; i < oTitle.length; i++) {
                    var major = Number.isInteger(parseFloat(oVersion[i]));
                    if(major){
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += "<td>"+ oVersion[i] +"</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + oTitle[i] +"</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + oEditor[i].split("#")[1] +"</td>";
                        html += "<td>" + oModified[i] +"</td>";
                        html += "</tr>";
                        break;
                    }

                }
    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML=table+html+"</table>";            
});

function getFieldVersion(fieldname){
                var versionContent = [];
                $().SPServices({
                                                operation: "GetVersionCollection",
                                                async: false,
                                                strlistID: "<list/library>",
                                                strlistItemID: currentItemId,
                                                strFieldName: fieldname,
                                                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                                                console.log(xData);
                                                console.log($(xData.responseText).find("Version"));
                                                $(xData.responseText).find("Version").each(function(i) {
                                                  console.log($(this).attr(fieldname) );
                                                  versionContent.push($(this).attr(fieldname));
                                                });  

                                                }
                                }); 
                return versionContent;                                                 
}
</script>
```